# How do I stop my Mac from syncing my whole library to my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, memory

Every time I plug my phone into my Mac, iTunes tries to synch hundreds of songs to my phone. If I just let it, it uses up all the available storage. I can't seem to find any menu option anywhere to stop the auto synch or to reverse the direction.

Answer (score 7):

This is fairly straightforward to disable. Follow these steps:

- Launch iTunes
- Go to iTunes > Preferences
- Select the *Devices* tab
- At the bottom, uncheck the *Prevent iPods, iPhones, and iPads from syncing automatically*
- Exit Preferences

Let us know if this doesn't resolve your issue.

Answer (score 5):

Once you've disabled the auto-sync as per Monomeeth's answer, you can then choose which songs it will transfer in future, at manual sync.

- Connect your phone.
- Launch iTunes.
- Wait for the phone icon to become solid, then click it.
  [image]
- Select Music on the left sidebar
- Select something other than Entire Music Library
  You can then choose which songs/playlists etc it should sync from lower down the page [not shown on photo as I have 'all' selected.]

[image]

Comment: My iTunes also has an "Automatically fill free space with songs" option, which presumably adjusts how many songs to add to the device based on the amount of free space available. You can also tweak this more finely: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/5900/5767